# json feed from cfc file not displaying in FullCalendar

Tags: json, events, fullcalendar, cfc

I am trying to pass events into FullCalendar using json and they are not displaying. Does anyone know if there is something wrong with the structure of my json?

CFC file:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfsetting showDebugOutput='No'>
    <cffunction access='remote' name='getEvents' >

        <cfset var events = [{'id'='10','title'='Urlaub','start'='2014-11-14 07:30:30','end'='2014-11-14 08:30:30'}]>

    <cfreturn serializeJSON(events)>

    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

CFM file:

```
eventSources:
        [
            {
                url: 'events_for_calendar_test.cfc?method=getEvents',
                color: 'yellow',
                textColor: 'black'
            }
        ]
```

JSON feed being passed:

[{"start":"2014-11-14 07:30:30","end":"2014-11-14 08:30:30","id":"10","title":"Urlaub"}]

Comment: Have you tried some different date formats?  I'm a fullcalendar novice but the various examples I see often use a 'yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss' type format.

Comment: yeah I tried that date format too. i can see the json in my network traffic and don't see anything that would mess it up: [{"start":"2014-11-14 07:30:30","end":"2014-11-14 08:30:30","id":"10","title":"Urlaub"}]

Comment: syntax looks ok to me. is it possible you have an invalid or duplicate ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wddxpacket was being added to the json by coldfusion serializeJSON. just had to add attributes to the function to make sure it only returned what I needed.

```
<cfcomponent>
<cfsetting showDebugOutput='No'>
<cffunction access='remote' name='getEvents' returnformat="JSON" returntype="String">
    <cfset var events = [{'id'='10','title'='Urlaub','start'='2014-11-14','end'='2014-11-14'}]>
    <cfreturn serializeJSON(events)>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Doh!! of course it was!  You were already CREATING json - you had no need to package it. Ha - that's a good gotcha right there.  Gald you solved it!

Comment: I'm not sure you even need the serializeJson() call... I think you can just do `<cfreturn events/>`.